# Set metadata in a lot of video files from command line

Tags: linux, bash, video, metadata

I have a few hundreds of video files in many subdirectories below a principal directory (say: my-videos). Files have extension equal to either .mp4 or .mkv or .avi. Many of them have a wrong "Movie name" metadata.

In a bash linux shell I would like to set the "Movie name" metadata equal to the value of the "Complete name" metadata (possibly without extension) in the quickest possible way.